# Parameter 'imageRef' is not used and Dexmerger failed- android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

[Error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYF0R.png)

i did multidexenabled true and clean,rebuild project.
the same error is happen..

> Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "za.co.riggaroo.motioncamera"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
ext {
    googlePlayServices = "11.8.0"
    firebaseUI = "2.3.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${googlePlayServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${googlePlayServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${googlePlayServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${googlePlayServices}"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    api "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:${firebaseUI}"
    api "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:${firebaseUI}"
    api "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:${firebaseUI}"
    api "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:${firebaseUI}"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're using versions of firebase-ui and google-play-services that are not compatible with each other. You should be using either a lower play-services version

```
ext {
    googlePlayServices = "11.0.4"
    firebaseUI = "2.3.0"
}
```

or higher firebase-ui version

```
ext {
    googlePlayServices = "11.8.0"
    firebaseUI = "3.2.2"
}
```

Check [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) for reference

Comment: it works but app not running on my mobile ..it shows runtime errors

Comment: Well, that's another problem isn't it?

Comment: yeah..the app runs when click run in android studio..but the app icon not showing in launcher

Comment: If that's another problem you should probably ask another question